# Get the element with in the array whose occurrence is 4 times

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array of strings , i want to find those element whose occurrence are 4 or more than 4 times with in the array.

my code

```
internal static void ProcessArray(string[] numArray)
        {
            string response = string.Empty;

            var duplicates = (numArray
                        .GroupBy(e => e)
                        .Where(e => e.Count() >= 4)
                        .Select(e => e.First())).ToList();
//do some further business logic
    }
```

So duplicate should return me  a list of string which has the element.

I am calling this from my method below

```
Public static string GetDuplicates()
{

 string[] s = new new string[]{" 1","1","2","2","2","1","3,"2","1" }
 string result = ProcessArray(s);
return result
}
```

it only returns 2 in the list , the correct result should be 1,2 in the list.

Comment: Please put this together as a [mcve] rather than part of a method and part of the input.

Comment: Your first `1` has whitespace. Either use `Trim` to truncate it or else if you are only working with integer parse your input into `int` using _Array.ConvertAll<T>_

Comment: @JonSkeet I have made the correction

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve]. Can I copy/paste/compile/run your code and see the incorrect result? Nope...

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = new string [] { "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "3", "2", "1" };
var groups = values.GroupBy(i => i).Select(i => new { Number = i.Key, Count = i.Count() });
foreach(var item in groups)
{
 if(item.Count == 4)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Number);
 }
}
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FqzFsk)**

Comment: Believe me or not, It is not me ;-) Just because I comment doesn't mean I downvote or upvote ;-)

Comment: @CodeNotFound i did not mean you! sorry